# Logistic regression with binary independant variables

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

I have searched high and low on the internet and cannot find the answer to my question.

I am conducting a logistic regression (glm) in r to find how input variables influence my dependant dichotomous value (present/absent).

My question is can my independent variables be in the form of 0 and 1, i.e. absent or present? If this is not possible why not and how would this impact my outcome?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, independent variables in linear models can be dichotomous, either `0` or `1`. These variables are usually called "dummy variable" and are frequently used for nominal data of all kinds. "dummy variable" will be a usefull search engine term.
Read the first sentence in this pdf: http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/statpage/logistic_eg1.pdf